# Setting up environments in classlibrary / nuget package in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget-package, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an application published in differents environments (Development, Staging and Production).

All of them are calling a single Nuget Package with the classlibrary I created.

How can I asign my application environment in the classlibrary so I can change the parameters of the generated nuget package?

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Why would your environments "call a Nuget source"? Wouldn't you deploy the application to the environment with the dependencies already pulled in?

Comment: A library should not be environment-specific. If you need to do different stuff for different environments, that should be covered by your usage of the library. For example, if you had a DAL library you should be injecting the connection string / context into that from your actual application, not configuring it at the library-level.